# How weird can the boundary be so that the fundamental theorems of vector calculus hold?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a connected open set in $\Bbb R^n$. Suppose that I want theorems in multivariables calculus like [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) or its relative like [Green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities) or even [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) to work, how wild can $\partial \Omega$ be?

Apparently piecewise smooth works, but I have seen weaker conditions as well. Does anyone have a good reference to books or papers that prove these result in a very general setting?

Comment: This is the subject matter of [geometric measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_measure_theory).

Comment: There is a trade off between what you assume on the functions and what you assume on the domain.  How smooth are your functions? Also, "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" by Evans and Gariepy is a possible source.

Comment: @Desire Let's assume that the functions are smooth enough so that their classical derivatives exist up to the required order. Do we get substantial improve on our generality of the domain in this case?

Comment: _Sobolev spaces_ by Vladimir Mazya discusses various properties of Sobolev functions on rough domains and also some counterexamples. I would look at extension and trace theorems there (although the case of smooth functions could be different).